# C++ How to Check if Array contents can add up to a specific number

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I got this Array:

```
int myArray[] = {2,5,8,3,2,1,9};
```

is ther any way I could check if some of the contents can add up to 20? I managed to check if any two values add up to 20 but I just don't know how to handle it if is irrelevant how many values it needs.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should add some sort of evidence that you have tried something, else everyone will think that you are just trying to get them to do your homework.

Comment: Sort and figure it out.

Comment: You will need a loop (or something equivalent) and an additional variable to calculate the sum.

Comment: Test 1 - sum all elements.  If the sum is smaller than your goal, then you can report no combination adds to goal.

Comment: This looks like a [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). You will probably need to evaluate all the possible combinations. You could speed it up by sorting the array and using [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), but for small enough arrays, enumerating all combinations should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you have a situation where you test if any combination of values satisfy a condition, you need to think of using recursion. You recurse through the elements and at each point branch off in two directions: one that considers that element, and one that doesn't. This can be short-circuited to stop looking if one of the branches does satisfy that condition.

Here's a potential solution to your problem

```
bool can_sum(const int* ptr, int size, int target, int total = 0)
{
    // check success
    if (total == target)
        return true;

    // check failure
    if (total > target || size == 0)
        return false;

    return can_sum(ptr+1, size-1, target, total + *ptr) // check with *ptr
        || can_sum(ptr+1, size-1, target, total);       // check without *ptr
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2,5,8,3,2,1,9};
    bool result = can_sum(arr, 7, 20);
    return 0;
}
```